# Constructing SQL query for retrieving tagged items

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following example, I have three MySQL (InnoDB) tables that contain the information about beverages and their characteristics.

1. The first table: "beverages" contains a number of different beverages.
2. Next table is "tags" which contains a characteristic that a beverage can have.
3. A beverage can have multiple tags, which is defined in the table "tagged".

**Table: beverages**

```
+------------------------+
|INT id | VARCHAR name   |
+------------------------+
|  1    |  coca-cola     |
+------------------------+
|  2    |  water         |
+------------------------+
|  3    |  mineral-water |
+------------------------+
```

**Table: tags**

```
+-------------------------+
|INT id | VARCHAR tagName |
+-------------------------+
|  1    |  clear          |
+-------------------------+
|  2    |  carbonated     |
+-------------------------+
|  3    |  flavoured      |
+-------------------------+
```

**Table: tagged**

```
+------------------------------------+
|INT id | INT beverageId | INT tagId |
+------------------------------------+
|  1    |  1             |  2        | (coca-cola is carbonated)
+------------------------------------+
|  2    |  1             |  3        | (coca-cola is flavoured)
+------------------------------------+
|  3    |  2             |  1        | (water is clear)
+------------------------------------+
|  4    |  3             |  1        | (mineral-water is clear)
+------------------------------------+
|  5    |  3             |  2        | (mineral-water is carbonated)
+------------------------------------+

The fields "beverageId" and "tagId" are foreign keys to the table "beverages".
```

I would like to construct a query that allows me to supply any number of tags, and the result would be all beverage id's that have all of these tags.
A query will include an arbitrary number of tags.

- If I supply tag id "2" (carbonated) and tag id "3" (flavoured), I will get back beverage id "1" (coca-cola).
- If I supply tag id "1" (clear), I will get back beverage id "2" (water) and id "3" (mineral water).
- If I supply tag "2" (carbonated), I will get back beverage id "1" (coca-cola) and beverage id "3" (mineral-water).

So the questions are;

1. For this purpose, is the table design appropriate?
2. How should this SQL query effectively be constructed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe following structure provides some guidance on what you can do.  Here is one approach where the tag ids are provided as separate variables:

```
select beverageid
from tagged t
group by beverageid
having sum(tagid = TAGID1) > 0 and
       sum(tagid = TAGID2) > 0 and
       . . . ;
```

Such a query could be a wee bit challenging to produce, because the number of clauses in the `having` clause varies.

Here is another approach, that assumes that the tagids are in a comma delimited list:

```
select beverageid
from tagged t
where find_in_set(tagid, TAGLIST) > 0
group by beverageid
having count(distinct tagid) = 
            (length(TAGLIST) - length(replace(TAGLIST, ',', '')) + 1;
```

The only slight confusion here is calculating the number of tags.

If you are constructing the query dynamically, then the following should perform the best when there is an index on `tagid`:

```
select beverageid
from tagged t
where tagid in (TAGLIST)
group by beverageid
having count(distinct tagid) = LENGTH OF TAGLIST;
```